# Change url with bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, regex, url, bookmarklet

Trying to write a javascript bookmarklet to jump from a front end link into a CMS edit page link.

So take a url like this

http://www.example.com/events/13097/article

and make a url like this

http://www.example.com/admin/edit.php?class=events&id=13097

I think I need to use regex to grab the class and id and then wrap it into a javascript function- but I'm a absolute beginner and wondering if someone can get me started?

Comment: You can also look into mod_rewrite if you're using apache (to do this on server side rather than relying on client side).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't *need* regex, Try this:

```
var url = ""+window.location;
var urlparts = url.split('/');
window.location = "http://www.example.com/admin/edit.php?class="+urlparts[3]+"&id="+urlparts[4];
```

splits the class and the id from the URL and repeats them in the redirect.
the first line casts the `window.location` to a string you could also use `String(window.location)` to do this, but that's more verbose.

to get the domain too, you can use:

```
"http://"+urlparts[2]+"/admin/edit.php?class="+urlparts[3]+"&id="+urlparts[4]
```

**EDIT:** Actually, you can get the `urlparts` with `window.location.href.split('/')` or to emulate the original code `window.location.toString().split('/')` other items of interest in the [`window.location` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.location) (examples from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10012966/change-url-with-bookmarklet/10013173#10013173) post)

```
hash: "#10013173"
host: "stackoverflow.com"
hostname: "stackoverflow.com"
href: "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10012966/change-url-with-bookmarklet/10013173#10013173"
origin: "http://stackoverflow.com"
pathname: "/questions/10012966/change-url-with-bookmarklet/10013173"
port: ""
protocol: "http:"
search: ""
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of the Regex to use in a C# unit test.  Since you're not familiar with regex, the pattern is the same as your source url, except with two [capture groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html): one for the class `(?<class>[^/]+)`, and one for the id `(?<id>[^/]+)`.  How each works is that it takes one or more characters (the plus) that isn't a slash `(^/)` and stores it in a regex group of the name in the angle brackets.

```
var source = "http://www.domain.com/events/13097/article";
var expected = "http://www.domain.com/admin/edit.php?class=events&id=13097";
var pattern = "http://www.domain.com/(?<class>[^/]+)/(?<id>[^/]+)/article";
var r = new Regex(pattern);
var actual = r.Replace(source, "http://www.domain.com/admin/edit.php?class=${class}&id=${id}");
Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//var str = window.location.href;
var str = "http://www.example.com/events/13097/article";
var re = /events\/(\d+)\//;
var match = str.match(re);
var newURL = "http://www.example.com/admin/edit.php?class=events&id=" + match[1];
alert(newURL);
```